# How To loop through php data into javascript object?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var mapArray = [];
          var mapObject = {};
</script>    
<?php while(have_rows('package_map')){
                the_row();
                $location = get_sub_field('package_map_points');
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
            mapObject.lat =  "<?= echo $location['lat']  ?>";
            mapObject.lng =  "<?= echo $location['lng'] ?>";
            mapArray.push(mapObject);
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

> Output should be : [{'lat' : 34234.23,'lng' : 32432342.13},{'lat' :
>   23234.23,'lng' : 635435.13}]

I Tried It but it only returning first record when i console it, is there any way where i can achieve this!

Comment: why are you using <?= when you already are setting it equal to something on the left hand side? Just try  mapObject.lat = <? echo $location['lat']

Comment: @PerrinPrograms is right.  At the least, you are going to have problems because you are trying to echo the unescaped-text `echo`.  If that alone doesn't solve your problem, it is probably an encoding issue.  Try `mapObject.lat =  "<?= json_encode($location['lat'])  ?>";`

Comment: If you have a php array of object with lat and lon properties, by json encoding the array you get the output you are looking for. I don't undersand what you want to do with the javascript but doesn't seem right.

Comment: thanks @Juan achieved it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix the PHP and Javascript, it's better to prepare the data in the PHP and "pass" it to the Javascript:

```
<?php
$locations = array();

while (have_rows('package_map')) {
    the_row();
    $locations[] = get_sub_field('package_map_points');
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
</script>
```